# ¿Como mostrar solamente la informacion del usuario logueado despues de iniciar sesion?

Tags: php, mariadb

Estos últimos días he estado teniendo problemas con un error el cual he intentado solucionar, recientemente empece a aprender PHP con MariaDB por lo que se que hay cosas a mejorar pero sin enrollarme mas les comento mi error.

Tengo una base de datos la cual contiene dos tablas, una llamada "registro_mascota" y la otra "registro_usuario" estas tablas están relacionadas con una llave foránea, la tabla "registro_mascota" tiene una columna llamada "usuario_id" la cual referencia la columna "id" de la otra tabla.

Lo que quiero lograr es que cuando un usuario inicie sesión automáticamente te muestre solamente la información del usuario logueado y no toda la información de la BD, tengo esta función la cual ya hace lo que necesito.

```
public static function userGetAll($conn, $userId)
{
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM registro_mascota
            JOIN registro_usuario ON registro_mascota.usuario_id = registro_usuario.id
            WHERE registro_usuario.id = :userId";
 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
 
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

El problema radica en que no se si hay error de lógica en esta función o en la forma que estoy logueando al usuario, tengo una clase llamada "Auth" la cual se encarga de autentificar al usuario

```
<?php
class Auth
{
    public static function requireLogin()
    {
        if (!static::isLoggedIn()) {
           
            Url::redirect("/offline.php?id=$id");
        }
    }

    public static function login($userId)
    {
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        $_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userId;
    }

    public static function logout()
    {
        
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
    }

    public static function isLoggedIn()
    {
       
        return isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']) && $_SESSION['is_logged_in'];
    }

    public static function getUserId()
    {
       
        return self::isLoggedIn() ? $_SESSION['user_id'] : null;
    }
}
```

y asimismo también estoy logueando al usuario de esta manera

```
<?php
require '/residencia/includes/init.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    $conn = require '/residencia/includes/db.php';

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (ListaUsers::authenticateAdmin($conn, $email, $password)) 
    {
        $userId = Auth::getUserId();
        Auth::login($userId);
        Url::redirect('/admin/lista_mascotas.php');
    } 
    elseif (ListaUsers::authenticate($conn, $email, $password)) 
    {
        $userId = Auth::getUserId();
        Auth::login($userId);
        var_dump($userId);
        Url::redirect('/lista_mascotas.php');
    } 
    else 
    {
        $error = "Error al iniciar sesión";
    }
}

?>
```

Otra cosa la cual olvide mostrar fue el como estoy autenticando a los usuarios como tal

```
  public static function authenticate($conn, $email, $password)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM registro_usuario
                WHERE email = :email";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'ListaUsers');
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($user = $stmt->fetch()) {
            return password_verify($password, $user->password);
        }

        return false; 
    }

    public static function authenticateAdmin($conn, $email, $password)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM registro_usuario
                WHERE type = 'admin' AND email = :email";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'ListaUsers');
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($user = $stmt->fetch()) {
            return password_verify($password, $user->password);
        }

        return false; 
    }
```

Y ya para finalizar en donde estoy intentando mostrar la información del usuario logueado es aquí, cabe mencionar que mi clase "userGetAll" se que funciona ya que la probe haciendo hardcoding del Id de un usuario existente en mi BD y efectivamente me muestra los datos registrados unicamente de este usuario.

```
<?php
require '/residencia/includes/init.php';
Auth::requireLogin();
$conn = require '/residencia/includes/db.php';


$userId = Auth::getUserId();

$registros_mascotas = ListaMascotas::userGetAll($conn, $userId);
var_dump($registros_mascotas);

?>

<?php require '/residencia/includes/header.php'; ?>
<title>Lista de mascotas</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php if (Auth::isLoggedIn()): ?>
    <p>Estás conectado. <a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesión</a></p>
    <p>Tu ID de usuario es: <?= htmlspecialchars($userId) ?></p>
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es la lista de mascotas por usuario creo que el `join` sobra. Sobre el problema hace un `var_dump($userId )` en el último código que has puesta y cuéntame que te aparece

Comment: No hagas **SELECT * FROM**, es mejor poner cada campo.

Comment: Al hacer `var_dump($userId)` me aparece NULL, por lo que ahora entiendo el que no me salga nada y en el caso de quitar el `join` como podría reformular esa parte del codigo para seguir obteniendo los resultados deseados? Muchas gracias por los consejos.

Comment: Ya reformule la parte del `join` pero sigo intentando resolver el otro problema.

Comment: Tienes un error de concepto, primero se [*autentica*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autenticación) y luego se autoriza. La idea de `ListaUsers::authenticateAdmin` implicaría **autorizar** como administrador al usuario; y nota que la autorización se relaciona mas con el login que con la entidad usuario.

Comment: Dejo este comentario solamente para decirles que el problema fue resuelto por completo, la autentificación de `user` y `admin` funciona correctamente, se obtiene la lista de información deseada y el sistema de logueo no da problemas.

Comment: @ErikRivera Y cual era el problema?

Comment: @Yussef edite mi caso arriba explicando lo que hice para resolverlo por si gustas leerlo pero el problema estaba en la funcion  `function authenticate` la cual no estaba retornando el ID del usuario (todos los codigos que puse arriba ya estan corregidos).

Comment: Puedes responder a tu propia pregunta, escribiendo una respuesta donde expliques cómo lo has resuelto. Sí editas la misma pregunta intentando explicar en ella la respuesta se crea una situación confusa donde futuros usuarios no entenderán nada. Es lo que me acaba de ocurrir, he leído todo y no he entendido ni el problema ni la solución. Esto no ayuda a nadie. Revierte la pregunta a como estaba y en una respuesta explica cómo lo has resuelto.

Comment: @A.Cedano Los primeros parrafos de la pregunta se encargan de describir la problematica por lo que no entiendo como que es no entiendes el problema pero tienes razon en la cuestion de la edicion, el problema es que ya no tengo el codigo que no funcionaba, ni en mi repositorio ni en VSC, tendre en cuenta esto para proximas preguntas o borrare esta pregunta para no confundir a nuevos usuarios.

Comment: No tienes que borrar la pregunta. Puedes recuperar el código viejo en el historial de ediciones. Se activa haciendo click en el icono de flecha circular de la izquierda, debajo de los puntos que tiene la pregunta.

Comment: Por otra parte, no se trata solamente de la utilidad que la pregunta pueda tener para futuros usuarios. Sí muestras claramente tu solución y vemos cosas que se pueden mejorar te lo diríamos. Pero en una mezcla pregunta/respuesta es mucho más complicado.

Comment: Ohh va, literalmente tengo dos dias por aqui asi que aun no estoy tan acostumbrado, entonces en un momento lo cambio.

Comment: Ahora está mejor, solo que a partir de *Resolví el problema, arriba esta el código original y después de este párrafo pondré los cambios que hice...* debe ser una respuesta, que puedes agregar en la parte de abajo. El sitio no funciona como un foro, funciona en base a preguntas que obtienen respuestas y no está prohibido que el mismo que pregunta se autoresponda.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código todavía se puede mejorar en varios aspectos que paso a enumerar:

1. Hay áreas no cubiertas. Por ejemplo, ¿hacia dónde se debe redirigir en caso de error, de fallo o de un resultado `false` o vacío?
2. En el segundo bloque de código, no deberías pasar a usar datos de superglobales sin estar seguro de que existen. Si no existen te verás expuesto a un *`Undefined index`*. Puedes usar fusión de null o ternarios en su defecto para asignar el valor. E incluso no lanzar la consulta si el valor fuese nulo o vacío.
3. En ese mismo bloque de código haces dos llamadas a `ListaUsers::authenticate($conn, $email, $password)`, si la primera no se cumple, volverías a llamar de nuevo al mismo método, lo cual no tiene sentido. Haz una sola llamada, guarda el resultado en una variable y luego verifica la variable. Lo que haces es más costoso, porque consultarías dos veces a la base de datos.
4. Puede que falte clarificar algunas cosas. Por ejemplo, estas dos llamadas sucesivas son sospechosas. `$userId = Auth::getUserId();` y `Auth::login($userId);`. Me refiero a que pasas de una a otra sin verificar nada. A mi juicio, deberías verificar primero el estado de `$userId` antes de pasar a `login()`. Por ejemplo, si `$userId` no existe o es nulo, no tiene sentido intentar un login. Además de eso, del login en sí mismo no hay verificación ninguna, aunque sí veo que tienes un método `isLoggedIn()` que no usas... No abundo más porque falta contexto, pero ese punto no parece claro aún en tu lógica.
5. Finalmente, puedes usar operadores ternarios, que te ayudarán a escribir un código más conciso, evitando algunos `if`.

Aplicando todo lo dicho, te propongo lo siguiente (se pude mejorar quizá, pero falta contexto):

```
<?php
require '/residencia/includes/init.php';
/*
    Declaramos una variable con el tipo de usuario 
    la inicializamos con un tipo error. La variable
    se quedará con ese valor si ninguno de los if se cumple
    y podremos redirigir a un path de error o hacer otra cosa
*/
$userType="error";
/*
    Declaramos un array para manejar las rutas
    Esto permitirá un código más limpio y mantenible
    Quitaremos los if e implementaremos una ruta de error 
    para que no haya vacíos en la lógica
*/
$paths=array('user'=>'/lista_mascotas.php', 'admin'=>'/admin/lista_mascotas.php', 'error'=>'/error');

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") 
{
    $conn = require '/residencia/includes/db.php';
    $email = !empty($_POST['email']) ?? null;
    $password = !empty($_POST['password']) ?? null;
    if ($email && $password) 
    {
        $userId = Auth::getUserId();
        if ($userId) 
        {
            Auth::login($userId);
            # Quizá se debería verificar si se logueó          
            $userType=ListaUsers::authenticate($conn, $email, $password);
        }
    }
}
/*
   OJO a esto: aquí veremos la gran utilidad de $paths
   Pasando el valor de $userType sabremos la URL 
   quitando así los if (imagina que en vez de 2 if fuesen 10 ó 50)
   MUY IMPORTANTE: Observa que en mi propuesta de código
   authenticate no devolverá false en caso de que 
   no haya nada, sino "error", para acoplarlo a lo definido en $paths.
   Si no quieres redirigir en caso de error, es relativamente fácil aquí
   verificar a $url con algo como if($url==='error') { hacer otra cosa}
   
*/  
$url=$paths[$userType];
Url::redirect($url);
?>
```

Y, como dijimos más arriba, mejoramos un poco el método `authenticate()` del siguiente modo:

```
<?php
public static function authenticate($conn, $email, $password)
{
    #Tipo de usuario inicializado a error por defecto
    $userType="error";
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM registro_usuario
            WHERE email = :email";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'ListaUsers');
    $stmt->execute();
    if ($user = $stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        if (password_verify($password, $user->password)) 
        {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
            $userType=($user->type === 'admin') ? 'admin' : 'user';
        }
    }
    # Si llega aquí retornará "error"
    return $userType;
}

?>
```

Me parece que de este modo el código queda más claro, menos verboso y más fácil de comprender y de mantener. Si hay alguna duda, pregunta en comentarios. Como dije, quedan quizá lagunas, porque me falta contexto.

Comment: `isLoggedIn` Si lo estoy usando para comprobar si la persona esta logueada o no, de ser el caso contrario te muestra dos enlaces ya sea para registrarte de no tener cuenta o iniciar sesión pero por temas de mantener encapsulada mi duda no copie y pegue todo mi código, aun así tomare tus recomendaciones en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada cambie la funcion userGetAll (esto no causaba un problema pero de esta forma se ve mas limpio y el join sobraba)

```
public static function userGetAll($conn, $userId)
{
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM registro_mascota
            WHERE usuario_id = :userId";
 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':userId', $userId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
 
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

El login fue reformulado, ahora solamente se manda llamar una funcion en vez de dos diferentes y simplemente se agrega la condicion de que si es `=== 'user'` la persona que inicio sesion se le mostrara solo lo debido de acuerdo a sus privilegios de cuenta y se aplica lo mismo con el `admin`.

```
<?php
require '/residencia/includes/init.php';

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    $conn = require '/residencia/includes/db.php';

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $userId = Auth::getUserId();
    Auth::login($userId);

    if (ListaUsers::authenticate($conn, $email, $password) === 'user')
    {
   
        Url::redirect('/lista_mascotas.php');
         
        
    } 
    
    elseif (ListaUsers::authenticate($conn, $email, $password) === 'admin')
    {
        Url::redirect('/admin/lista_mascotas.php');
      
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Error al iniciar sesión";
    }
}


?>
```

Ahora en donde tenia el problema principal es que la función que servia para autenticar al usuario no estaba retornando el `ID` por lo que la tuve que modificar para que si lo hiciera ademas de esto junte las funciones `authenticateAdmin` y `authenticate` para hacerlas una sola y evitar código innecesario.

```
    public static function authenticate($conn, $email, $password)
{
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM registro_usuario
            WHERE email = :email";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'ListaUsers');
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($user = $stmt->fetch()) {
        if (password_verify($password, $user->password)) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;

            if ($user->type == 'admin') {
                return 'admin';
            } else {
                return 'user';
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```